# Material Design Colors fit

Tags: color, color-theory, google-material-design

I am trying to do applications in material design style but it is not always has best colour palette.

I have this screen and this  bottom buttons colour really bothers me because it is hard to see them. Likewise if I try to use here some kind of light-blue as button colours it would be too bright.

What colour or trick use in this kind of situation?

[image]

Comment: Material gives you a broad spectrum of color recommendations, but you aren't limited to them. In this case, your buttons look deactivated because they are a fade of your primary color. Read up on the many questions here on [tag:color-theory] and come back when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/color-palettes.html
Google give to us a borad of palletes but you dont have to limited to them experiment whit diferentcolors and check other apps for inspiration. good luck and keep desing dude!

Comment: Thanks, I read it) I am really talking abot this situation and not abstract